# [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error

Tags: iis, asp-classic, ado, ssl-security

Our ASP/IIS web server talks to a SQL 2005 db server.

Eventually, without a pattern, some pages start showing error instead of the page content:

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error.

Rebooting web server resolves it.

Anyone know about it?

Comment: what versions of .NET and IIS are you running. What Service Packs have you applied for .NET, MDAC and SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things you should look at:

- Low bandwidth to the DB server (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322144)
- Problematic certificates on the DB server, e.g. self-signed certificates
- SQL Authentication mode - Windows only, or SQL and Windows

Answer (score 0):

In case others happen to come across this when their certs expire and wonder why their SQL Server is giving SSL errors...

This worked for me after removing unwanted certs... setting Certificate=0 in registry:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib REG_SZ Certificate=0

Read more about it here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/taraj/archive/2009/01/07/sql-server-the-best-database-server-to-work-on.aspx